# using generics in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have created this class that works with generics in  TypeScript

```
export class ModelTransformer {

    static hostelTransformer: HostelTransformer;

    static fromAtoB(instance: T): U {
        if (instance instanceof HostelType) {
            return ModelTransformer.hostelTransformer.fromAtoB (instancet);
        }
    }

}
```

But when I compile it I have those compilation errors:

> src/model/transformer/model.transformer.ts:11:47 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.

```
11     static fromAtoB(instance: T): U {
```

> src/model/transformer/model.transformer.ts:11:51 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'U'.

```
11     static fromAtoB(instance: T): U {
```

I have tried the solution proposed, but then I have this error:

> error TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.

Comment: additionally to the Bauke's answer: you need to change the returning type of your method to `U | void`, for example, since it doesn't return anything in case instance is not instanceof HostelType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a "type variable" as described [in the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables), like so:

```
static fromAtoB<T, U>(instance: T): U {
    if (instance instanceof HostelType) {
        return ModelTransformer.hostelTransformer.fromAtoB (instancet);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but because `U` doesn't have a lower bound and isn't provided as a type argument to `fromAtoB`, then it's still going to have a type error unless `fromAtoB`'s return type is `any`, `never` or another not-lower-bounded type parameter. (Not that Typescript currently supports lower bounds for type variables.)